# Given the Java Stacktrace a tool that give diff between two releases

Tags: git, github, github-api

We have production servers logging exceptions stack trace, and I would like to build a tool given the exception stack Trace to show diff between all the files change from release r1 and new release r2 (based on the Stack Trace).  Does git or any thing that provides this functionality ?  After diff, this tool will notify user who modified files with stack trace.  We store our code in local github repository.

Comment: I highly doubt something this sophisticated exists. If you're using a CI server, it can always notify you when things have broken after a commit.

Answer (score 1):

You have two challenges:

**Compare View:**

Github has this feature built in, it's the compare view. If just need to specify two branches/tags, like this:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/compare/v3.1.0...v3.1.1

I've used twitter bootstrap as an example. I'm comparing all the changes between these two points in the commit tree. `v3.1.0` and `v.3.1.1` are tags, but you can use:

- branches
- tags
- commitIds

Try it yourself in one of your projects, just hit:

```
https://github.com/<org>/<repo>/compare/<start>...<end>
```

The file changed tab on the compare view will tell you what lines were changed, and the commits view will tell you who worked on these files. For additional info you can query the [Github API](http://developer.github.com/v3/) for more details on the commits.

**Stacktrace reporting**

Now your tool just needs to crawl through the previous compare view and extract the information you require.

A more professional solution would use the [Github API](http://developer.github.com/v3/) for everything, but this might do based on your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the answers I will try..is there is any open source tool available let me know .  Thanks.